# Precedence of stored vs docValues in solr

Tags: solr, lucene, full-text-search, solrcloud

If I have set both stored=true and docValues=true for a given field as follows,

what would be the precedence chosen by solr? As in, is it like, if I am doing a sort/facet operation on the id field, the value will be retrieved from docValues and if I am executing a normal search query which returns id field, it will be returned from stored field ?

Please help me to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stored` values aren't used for anything other than returning the value to the client - i.e. what value was submitted for the field when it was sent to Solr. So yes, if you perform a search (or anything that results in *a document* being returned to the client), the stored value is read and returned.

`docValues` implements an actual feature in Lucene that makes certain operations more effective (such as sorting and faceting as you've mentioned). They're a lower level feature, and you don't really "see" the underlying stored docvalues.

I'm guessing you're confusing these values since there's support for "use doc values as stored value"; in certain cases the value stored in a docvalue will be the same as the same as what the user submitted (for example for integer fields), so if Lucene has already read and used the docvalue - and it is compatible with the stored value, you can tell it to skip fetching the stored value as well - saving a read.